# Generating String Arrays based on regular expression on the input String Array

Tags: scala

```
User_Info:Array[String]=("Brian McNamee (Canada) 16th October 2015",    "Claudia Stanzani 18th September 2009", ..)
```

This is what I intend:

```
Expecting Output: Array[(String,String,String)]=Array(("Brian McNamee", "Canada", "16th October 2015"),("Claudia Stanzani", "", "18th September 2009")
```

How I am trying:

```
val pattern="(.+)\\((.+)\\)(.+)".r //pattern variable accepts all the RDDs that contain (<country>)
val default_pattern="(.+)\\s(.+)".r //default pattern variable marking the place country column column empty


 val User_profiles= User_Info.map{
         | case pattern(name, country, year) => (name, country, year)
         | case default_pattern(name, country, year) =>(name, "", year)}
```

But this results in disobeying my regex pattern for the string array :

> Array((Brian McNamee (Canada) 16th October,"",2015),("Claudia Stanzani
>   18th September","","2009")

what's really going wrong, is it because of the regex that's badly defined or pattern match? Or both? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the default match case, skip matching for a `country` but rather try match date that (presumably) starts with `day` (e.g. 15th, 2nd, etc), as in the following:

```
val User_Info: Array[String] = Array(
  "Brian McNamee (Canada) 16th October 2015", "Claudia Stanzani 18th September 2009"
)

val pattern="""(.*?)\s*\((.*)\)\s*(.*)""".r
val default_pattern="""(.*?)\s*(\d+st|\d+nd|\d+rd|\d+th)(.*)""".r

val User_profiles = User_Info.map{
  case pattern(name, country, year) => (name, country, year)
  case default_pattern(name, day, monthyear) => (name, "", day + monthyear)
}
// User_profiles: Array[(String, String, String)] = Array(
//   (Brian McNamee,Canada,16th October 2015), (Claudia Stanzani,"",18th September 2009)
// )
```

Note that the Regex match for the date can be more stringent if wanted (for example, limit digit for `day` to be 1 to 2 digits, make `month` to be exactly one of the 12 months and `year` to be 4-digit, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your `default_pattern`.

1. It has 2 capture groups so `case default_pattern(name, country, year)` will never match. This will work: `case default_pattern(name, year)` but...
2. There are no rules for determining where `name` ends and `year` (i.e. date info) begins. The current pattern puts everything into `name` except for the final space-delimited word.

You actually don't need the `default_pattern` at all, but then the `pattern` gets a little bloated.

```
val pattern=
  """(?x)              # allow regex comments, ignore whitespace
     ([^\d(]+)         # name, no digits or "("
     (:?\((\D+)\)\s*)? # (country), optional, no digits
     (\d\S+)\s+        # day, starts with digit, no spaces
     (\S+)\s+          # month, no spaces
     (\d+)             # year, digits only
  """.r

User_Info.map{
   case pattern(name, _, country, day, month, year) =>
     (name.trim, Option(country).getOrElse(""), s"$day $month $year")
   case _ => throw new Error
}
```